# Set multiple roots for a rails app + unicorn + nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I need a help to set some roots in a same server when use unicorn+nginx with rails apps.

My app works when I set only a root.

```
upstream contab_teste {
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/apps/contab/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name default_server;
  rails_env production;
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html @app;
  root /home/ubuntu/apps/contab/public;
  location @app {
      proxy_pass http://contab_teste;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

When I set another root directory its not works.
I tried in some ways to do like this:

```
upstream contab_teste {
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/apps/contab/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream contab_apresentacao {
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/apps/contab_apresentacao/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name default_server;
  rails_env production;
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html @app;
  root /home/ubuntu/apps/contab/public;
  location @app {
      proxy_pass http://contab_teste;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /apresentacao {
      #rewrite ^/apresentacao(.*) /$1 break;
      root /home/ubuntu/apps/contab_apresentacao/public;
      proxy_pass http://contab_apresentacao;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Someone can help me please?
thanks!